# I want to get the id value from database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to delete a row from my data-table so I need to get the id value from database and then delete it.

```php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM registre where id=$id");
```

This code doesn't get the id value from database, I don't have a row for id in my data-table so I need to get from to db and then delete it.

Comment: "doesn't work for me" isn't very descriptive. What doesn't work?

Comment: you have a syntax error it should be `$result=mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM registre where id=".$id);`

Comment: Also, when using variables that are exterior to the script, make use of prepared statements. Would advise checking [Preventing Mysql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Are you sure the table name is correct ( 'registre' ) or it may be 'register'

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it?  Is there an error?  What is the value of `$id`?  What is the value of `$result`?  Does `mysqli_error` show you an error?  You have to tell us what the problem *is* before we can help solve it.

Comment: @JayBlanchard 
the table in db have ( 'id','name','url' ) i need to get that id value and delete the row from mt datatable , but my code doesnt get the id value from the db

Comment: @AyoubAbouhilal: *"but my code doesnt get the id value from the db"* - The code you have doesn't "get" anything, it "deletes".  If you're trying to "get" data then the query keyword you want is called `SELECT`.  It's still really not clear what the actual problem is here.

Comment: Are you thinking that the $_GET superglobal automatically gets information from your database?

Answer (score 0):

Try this using prepated statement  :

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM registre where id= ?");
$bind = $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$exec = $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: you mean that is not the purpose ?

Comment: what does the prepated statement do

Comment: While this is good general advice, how does it address the question being asked?  What even is the question being asked?

Comment: @AyoubAbouhilal , it's for preventing sql injection , see the link here for more details : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @AyoubAbouhilal Prepared statements are the only correct way of passing data to the SQL statements. You should never concatenate data in SQL.

Answer (score -1):

Try this maybe it helps

```html
$id = $_GET['id'];
 $result = mysqli_query($con, 'DELETE FROM registre where id=' . $id);
```